# Any example of useful pointer arithmetic in Objective-C / iOS programming?

Tags: objective-c, ios, c, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

I am aware of the existence of pointer arithmetic in C, but can anyone cite any example of why pointer arithmetic is *ever* useful in Objective-C programming for iOS? I am stumped...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is used in quite a bit of places actually, here is just a few...

- Array Access

Whenever you use a C Array and you access an individual element (lets say array[12], it is actually interpreted as *(array+12)

- OpenGLES

If you have ever used this, it makes extensive use of pointer arithmetic on iOS, when it is necessary to pack multiple arrays into an interleaving array you must use offsetof, which then gets added to the memory buffer to get the full location of the attribute.

- Fast Enumeration

By using pointer arithmetic you can speed up enumeration of elements by incrementing the actual pointer instead of an individual variable.

- Easier Programming of Certain Data Structures

Certain data structures such as a deque are much easier to implement with pointer arithmetic.

Answer (score 2):

Pointer arithmetic is NOT used in objective C.  The question was what use would it be.  The answer is NONE.

Using a C array as the example above suggests is not a usage of objective C its a usage of C.  Objective C arrays have built in enumeration capabilities as well as the normal for syntax using the .count property.

To answer the question, pointer arithmetic is not used in objective C itself because they are not necessary and not supported by obj c array pointers.

Answer (score 1):

All pointer arithmetic in Objective C is the derived from Objective C being a strict superset of C, there is no usage for that in objective c not derived from C.

Comment: Yep. You want a fast, efficient array of integers: use plain old C with pointer arithmetics, the classical way.

Answer (score 0):

I assume it was very useful for the people who developed fast enumeration (i.e. the for-in loop).

Comment: Is the `for (id object in array)` not part of C??

Comment: @jshin47 - no it's not, yet I fail to understand how will it use the pointer arithmetic.

Comment: @BinyaminSharet Doesn't it offset the memory location by the size of the objects it contains to get the next object?  Isn't that pointer arithemetic or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @borrrden - OK, but this is part of the framework implementation, it  isn't something that the developer does.

Comment: @BinyaminSharet I tried to word it in such a way to make that apparent (not something used in normal development)...I guess I failed :(.  The people who developed the framework are developers too though, and this question said when is it *ever* useful.

Comment: @borrrden so `for-in` works by adding `sizeof(a_objc_struct)` to the mem location?? really?

Comment: @jshin47 I don't have the source so I can't say **exactly** what it does, but it is a reasonable assumption that it does it that way.  That is how regular C-arrays work too.  Whenever you type foo bar[3], what you are actually saying is "give me the address of bar, offset by 3 sizes of a foo pointer"  (or (*bar + 3))